# How can I extend logical volume to 100%?

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I have a 5 Gb drive. I've created a pv, then a vg, and then a logical volume size 2GB with `sudo lvcreate -L +2GB -n lv-test vg-test`. Then I formatted this volume with: `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg-test/lv-test` and mounted it with: `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/lv-test`

Now I want to extend this logical volume to 100%FREE (to all size of disk -- 5GB). When I ran `lvextend 100%FREE /dev/vg-test/lv-test`, the LV extends only in 1 GB. Now it's 3GB. What's wrong? How I can extend it to 5GB?

```
user@ubuntu2:~$ sudo pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdj
  VG Name               vg-test
  PV Size               5.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1279
  Free PE               512
  Allocated PE          767
  PV UUID               N5fWom-E678-uzKn-c4Dt-ielb-57GN-9h2kfm
user@ubuntu2:~$ sudo vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg-test
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <5.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1279
  Alloc PE / Size       767 / <3.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       512 / 2.00 GiB
  VG UUID               ZCjGyZ-n1Rs-bT8d-z0cg-k8fO-9d2J-Fonggh
user@ubuntu2:~$ sudo lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg-test/lv-test
  LV Name                lv-test
  VG Name                vg-test
  LV UUID                GYtquF-h2H7-Ys2k-ec9G-BH00-ToTj-NY2Vdo
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu2, 2022-02-21 20:46:54 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                <3.00 GiB
  Current LE             767
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
user@ubuntu2:~$ sudo lvextend -l 100%FREE vg-test/lv-test
  New size given (512 extents) not larger than existing size (767 extents)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to *add* all the free space, so need a `+`:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vg-test/lv-test
```

Without that, you’re asking that the LV occupy the free space only.

Comment: Also, to create logical volume directly: `sudo lvcreate -l +100%FREE -n lv-test vg-test`

Comment: If you’re creating a LV, the `+` isn’t necessary; that’s the subtlety in the question.